# SQL Server merge function - Delete and output deleted not working properly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a pretty standard script that uses the merge functionality to insert, update, and delete records. However, I am having a lot of trouble with outputting deleted results to an audit type table. When I run the procedure against a clean target table I somehow end up with all nulls in the audit table, despite the fact nothing has been deleted (only inserts to non-audit table at this point, which does happen as it should). Under the same conditions and against the same clean target table, if I remove the:

```
OUTPUT deleted.Column1, deleted.Column2 INTO Table_Audit (Column1, Column2)
```

and replace it with:

```
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*
```

I see that nothing has actually been deleted, which is odd considering the source and target tables were the same on both runs and the merge predicate remained the same. All the records in the action column of the second statement are inserts as we would expect. Literally the only thing different is what I just mentioned above. Any ideas as to what could be going on?

Comment: I do realize a temporary workaround for this is to create a temp table, pass results of OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.* into said temp table, and populate audit table from there. However, the way I would like to achieve things is much cleaner and should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [example K](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Put your merge statement in a subquery to a insert statement against your audit table. Make sure one of the columns is `$action` and filter the values to insert in the outer where clause to only insert deleted rows.

Comment: I did not take into account that deleted.* lumps together actions updated and deleted.

Comment: @TechDawg270 It's not `deleted.*` that is to blame. The output clause returns one row for each change (insert/update/delete) and in the case for update you can access the new value in `inserted` and the old value in `deleted`.

Comment: But I thought since the deleted.* lived within a delete statement that it knew only to touch rows deleted, similar to what would happen if the output deleted.* was contained within an update statement

Comment: @TechDawg270 `deleted` does not "live" in the deleted statement. It is part of the output statement and is as I said also populated when you do updates. The output statement will always return as many rows as has been modified in some way.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, Is this the only way?. I also came across a situation in which I want only the DELETED records to be OUTPUT from a Merge statement.

Comment: @JithinShaji It is the only way I know of.